# When does gdb mark a variable as "not available"?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm fairly new to GDB and I haven't found a similar question yet and my Googling has been in vain, so here goes.

I'm connecting to a remote PowerPC-based board through a COM port, using GDB, and I've hit a breakpoint. Here's my (very edited) GDB session.

```
(gdb) where
#0 WaitForStuff () at graphfile.c:1234
#1 0x00012af4 in WaitForOtherStuff () at graph.c:2345
#2 0x001d0a7c in DrawScreens (DefaultScreenFct=0x2bef02 <DefaultFct>,
SecondScreenFct=0x2bef02 <DefaultFct>, DrawBothPages=Variable "DrawBothPages"
is not available.
[...]
(gdb)
```

Here is the declaration of the function at frame #2 :

```
void DrawScreens(void (*DefaultScreenFct)(void), void (*SecondScreenFct)(void),
const BOOLEAN DrawBothPages);
```

This is where I'm lost : why is this variable "not available" and how could I make it "available"? I've compiled the program using GCC with the -g3 switch just in case I needed more info but I get the same error. I've also removed the -O flag we used. Could it be the `BOOLEAN` typedef (simply an `unsigned char`) ? Or possibly the `const`ness of the parameter ? I find it strange that GDB would not even give me an address I could look at.

Thank you !

Comment: Try -O0 as an gcc flag. This is for "no optimization". No -O flag doesn't necessarily mean to optimization

Comment: What does GCC say is the `target:` when you use the `-v` option.

Comment: Having removed the optimisation, did you ensure that the file was recompiled?  An incremental build may not have caused recompilation.

Comment: @Michael Blurr : `Target: powerpc-eabi` which is the right target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-O` turns *on* optimization in GCC (it's equivalent to `-O1`).

You want to use `-O0` to turn optimization off (and is the default).

Also, the PowerPC's ABI probably passes parameters in registers.  I don't know if `-O0` would cause GCC to mirror the argument onto a stack memory location in the function or not.

Comment: My bad ! That's what I meant : I removed the -O flag that was in my CFLAGS so now I use the default case. I'll edit my question to make that clearer.

Comment: @SolarBear: don't remove it. State explicitly `-O0`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is in a register and which has been flushed or aliased to something else.

Comment: Do you any source or material supporting that answer ? And, any solution to the problem itself ?

Comment: @SolarBear: from experience and documentation about PPC and GDB I can second his remark.